# Why do i get a segmentation fault when executing this C program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When i execute this program i get a segfault and don't know why.
It should return the factorial(?) of the input as long as it is bigger than 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int input) 
{
    if (input > 0)
    {
    return input * factorial(input--);
    }
    else
    {
    return 1; 
    }
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d", factorial(23));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x * somefunc(x--)` provokes UB anyways.

Comment: Another issue you will encounter is that your program only computes the factorial function as long as the result fits in a `int`, and overflows otherwise.

Comment: A single `printf` inside the function should have shown the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`factorial(input--)` does not do what you think it does. Use `factorial(input-1)`.

Here is a [page that documents the post-decrement operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) that should help in using it correctly. You **never** have to use it. You can always do what you intend with `+`, `-`, and `=` (assignment).

Your program is producing a segmentation fault because as you have written it, `factorial(23)` calls `factorial(23)`, resulting in a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).